# Putting latex axis labels through gnuplot and into a latex document

Tags: graphics, latex, gnuplot

I have a plot in Gnuplot which includes axis labels in latex font, which compiles to produce a *.tex file AND a *.eps file. When I put the eps file into my latex document, the axis labels simply do not appear at all. When I try to imbed the *.tex file (which references the EPS), I get:

! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in dimensionlessformm5d.tex (no BoundingBox).

What is a BoundingBox and how do I add it in to the *.tex file I want to imbed?

Comment: Please give a minimal but fully runnable example of what you're doing. There are some many pitfalls, that its difficult to guess. The most probably error is, that you don't use `\input{dimensionlessformm5d}` to include the graphic in your main document.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell with no code, but you should be able to compile without specifying bounding box (are you loading the graphicx package? Use `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your latex preamble). In any case, you can get a bounding box with

```
gs -sDEVICE=bbox -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH file.eps
```

and specify on latex using

```
\includegraphics[bb = insert 4 bounding box values here]{file.eps}
```

Post you gnuplot and latex codes if you want more directed advice.

Answer (score -1):

Latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,fleqn,amssymb,graphicx}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}


\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.995\textwidth]{dimensionlessformm5d.tex}
\caption{Dimensionless output 1: Spectral plot of the negative value of the real part of Eq. (\ref{eqn:new22}) in units of $\tau^2 / \gamma_i$ plotted vs. normalized frequency $\omega / \omega_L$ for $\omega_L \tau = 75$ (black curve),250(green),1000(magenta), for a value of the dimensionless initial momentum $p_i / (m^{\prime} c^{\prime})$ of 2.375. Note that the independent variables have been expressed in dimensionless form for ease of scaling analysis. Note also that this is simply the fractional single-pass gain, except lacking the prefactor $e^2 Z_0\dot{n}/(4m)$.}
\end{figure}



\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{paper1} Borie, E. "Review of Gyrotron Theory". Tech. no. 4898. Karlsruhe, Germany: Kernforschungszentrum Karlsruhe, 1991. {\it Karlsruher Institut Fuer Technologie.} Web. 21 Nov. 2012. \textless http://bibliothek.fzk.de/zb/kfk-berichte/KFK4898.pdf\textgreater .

\bibitem{paper2} "Efficiency Enhancement of the Relativistic Gyrotron" N. A. Zavolsky, V. E. Zapevalov and M. A. Moiseev (Radiophysics and Quantum Electronics
Volume 44, Number 4 (2001), 318-325, DOI: 10.1023/A:1010422204317) Web. 21 Nov. 2012.
\textless http://www.springerlink.com/content/g15665j442405407/\textgreater .

\bibitem{paper3} Coyne, Kristen. "Magnets from Mini to Mighty." National High Magnetic Field Laboratory. N.p., n.d. Web. 21 Nov. 2012. \textless http://www.magnet.fsu.edu/education/tutorials/magnetacademy/magnets/fullarticle.html\textgreater .

\bibitem{paper4} Min, Hongki. "Electronic Structure of Graphene Graphene Monolayer Graphene Bilayer." Lecture. 11 Oct. 2006. Web. 21 Nov. 2012. \textless http://www.ph.utexas.edu/~macdgrp/meetings/hongki-monolayer.pdf\textgreater .


\bibitem{paper5} “Band gap formation in graphene by in-situ doping” (Appl. Phys. Lett. 98, 203102 (2011) doi: 10.1063/1.3589364)

\bibitem{paper6} “Universal Optical Conductance of Graphite”, Phys. Rev. Lett. 100, 117401 (2008)

\bibitem{paper7} “Intersubband Electroluminescence from Silicon-Based Quantum Cascade Structures” Science 22 December 2000
Vol. 290 no. 5500 pp. 2277-2280
DOI: 10.1126/science.290.5500.2277

\bibitem{paper8} Andronov, Alexander A. "From H. Kroemer and B. Lax to Modern Solid-State (Semiconductor) Cyclotron Resonance Masers." IEEE Transactions on Plasma Science 27.2 (1999): 303-11. Print.

\end{thebibliography}




% To be more explicit about losses, the mirror parameters’ relation to each other, and cavity performance is also
% included via the following equations.
% $CL=1-[(1-MT-MA)(1-GA)]$
% where $CL$ is the cavity loss,
% $MT$ is the mirror Transmission coefficient,
% $MA$ is the mirror Absorption coefficient,
% and $GA$ is the graphene Absorption coefficient.



% and we take the new fields E parallel and E perp to be slowly varying in time compared to the gyration at
% $\omega_{Larmor}$

\end{document}
```

Gnuplot code:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "C:\\Users\\cole1\\Desktop\\dimensionlessformm5d.eps"

set multiplot
set xtics font "Times-Roman, 20"
set ytics font "Times-Roman, 18"

set size 1,1
set origin 0,0
set xlabel "blahblah"

set xrange [0.35:0.8]
set yrange [-2:1]
plot 'C:\\Users\\cole1\\Documents\\MATLAB\\theorycurves3_1.txt' using 1:2 lc rgbcolor "#000000" with lines notitle, 'C:\\Users\\cole1\\Documents\\MATLAB\\theorycurves3_1.txt' using 7:8 lc rgbcolor "#00FF00" with lines notitle , 'C:\\Users\\cole1\\Documents\\MATLAB\\theorycurves3_1.txt' using 11:12 lc rgbcolor "#FF00FF" with lines notitle 
unset label 1
```

Comment: What the hell... Assuming that you have two accounts: Please edit the question to add the code! Have you read my comment about including tex files? And: Your script generates an `eps` file. Please order your stuff before posting it!

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and I'm getting "LaTeX Warning: inputting 'fleqn.clo' instead of obsolete 'fleqn.sty'. And it's also giving me an "Undefined Control sequence" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Again: Please clean up you stuff! `fleqn` has nothing to do in a minimal document and has nothing to do with gnuplot. What control sequence is undefined? You still have a gnuplot script which outputs an eps file, but you try to include a tex file (which isn't generated by this script) which an \includegraphics... Either you use `set terminal postscript eps; set output 'file.eps'` and include this image with `\includegraphics{file}`, *or* you use `set terminal epslatex; set output 'file.tex'` and use `\input{file.tex}` to include it.